# MailQueue implementation with auto start - stop

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, email

[Previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87732/concurrentlinkedqueue-to-unmodifiable-list) was a little portion of the `mailQueue`.

I finished the `MailQueue`, which has the ability to start and stop itself. I also implemented some more threads for sending when the load becomes greater. This is because we do send at some points over the 15000 mail in a short time. The last `MailQueue` did need 2hrs after adding mail to empty the `Queue`.

```
public enum MailQueue implements Runnable {

    INSTANCE;

    private JavaMailSender sender;
    private boolean run = false;

    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MimeMessage> mailsToSend = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MimeMessage>();
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MimeMessage> errorRun = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MimeMessage>();
    private final Map<MimeMessage, MailException> mailsWithErrors = new ConcurrentHashMap<MimeMessage, MailException>();

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailQueue.class);
    private static final int WAIT_FAILURE_TIME = 120000;
    private static final int MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL = 4;
    private static final int MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD = 25;
    private static final AtomicInteger CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        run = true;
        CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.getAndIncrement();
        while (run) {
            while (mailsToSend.peek() != null) {
                int currentThreads = CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.get();
                if (currentThreads < MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL && mailsToSend.size() > (MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD * currentThreads)) {
                    new Thread(this).start();
                }
                MimeMessage message = mailsToSend.remove();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
        if (CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.decrementAndGet() < 1) {
            getErrorThread().start();
        }
        run = false;
    }

    /**
     * Adding a mail to the Queue.
     * When Queue is not started, it will start.
     * @param message to send.
     * @return true is mail is successfully added to the Queue
     */
    public boolean addMail(MimeMessage message) {
        boolean result = mailsToSend.add(message);
        if (!run) {
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Adding a mail to the Queue.
     * When Queue is not started, it will start.
     * @param messages to send.
     * @return true is mail is successfully added to the Queue
     */
    public boolean addMails(Set<MimeMessage> messages) {
        boolean result = mailsToSend.addAll(messages);
        if (!run) {
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Removes a specific mail from the error list.
     * @param message to remove
     * @throws MessagingException When there is a fault with getting recipients for logging.
     * Mail is NOT removed when this error comes up.
     */
    public void removeMailFromError(MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException {
        LOGGER.info("Removed mail to " + message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)[0].toString()
                + "\nWith title : " + message.getSubject() + "from error queue. \nError was : " + mailsWithErrors.remove(message).getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * Starts a new Thread, to try sending the erroneous mails again.
     */
    public void startErrorThread() {
        getErrorThread().start();
    }

    /**
     * Try to send this specific mail from error list.
     * @param message to send
     * @return True if mail was send.
     */
    public boolean trySingleErrorMail(MimeMessage message) {
        if (sendMessage(message)) {
            LOGGER.trace("erroneous mail succesfull send", mailsWithErrors.remove(message));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Thread getErrorThread() {
        return new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wait(WAIT_FAILURE_TIME);
                tryErrorsAgain();
            }

            private void wait(int time) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    LOGGER.error("sleep interrupted.", ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void tryErrorsAgain() {
        errorRun.addAll(mailsWithErrors.keySet());
        while (errorRun.peek() != null) {
            MimeMessage message = errorRun.remove();
            if (sendMessage(message)) {
                MailException exception = mailsWithErrors.remove(message);
                if (exception != null) {
                    LOGGER.trace("Errorneous mail succesfull send.", exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean sendMessage(MimeMessage message) {
        MailException exception;
        try {
            sender.send(message);
            return true;
        } catch (MailException e) {
            try {
                LOGGER.error("sending mail failed " + String.valueOf(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)[0]), e);
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("This error shouldn't happen.", ex);
            }
            exception = mailsWithErrors.put(message, e);
            if (exception != null) {
                LOGGER.trace("Added duplicated mail in errors", e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public MimeMessage createMimeMessage() {
        return sender.createMimeMessage();
    }

    public MailQueue setSender(JavaMailSender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
        return this;
    }

    public Map<MimeMessage, MailException> getMailsWithErrors() {
        return mailsWithErrors;
    }

    public Collection<MimeMessage> getToSend() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(mailsToSend.toArray(new MimeMessage[0])));
    }

    public boolean isRun() {
        return run;
    }
}
```

Comment: We had issues when connecting more than one concurrent thread to the same server (gmail ) especially, they would make us as spam! Workaround : new public IP and code to make sure only one thread open to one remote server per our public IP

Comment: `     new Thread(this).start();` is a very bad way of making and managing threads. Use a thread pool executor and then make tasks to process mails in it. A task could be to send one mail or till it has none in queue. Also in run method out a try-catch-Throwable - most books and experts will tell u not to do that, but if some weird error occurs in prod, without that your logs wont have a clue why a thread exited. so only once in main run method put a try-catch-Throwable with log for a catch-all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private boolean run = false;
```

A verb as a variable name seems weird to me. Especially as a boolean. Try to make your booleans adjectives, questions or statements instead. In this case, I'd go for `running`.

You'd get an aptly named `isRunning` method from this too, rather than `isRun`.

---

```
public enum MailQueue implements Runnable {

    INSTANCE;
```

What the...

This is clever abuse of language mechanics, and I don't like it for that specific reason.

Do it the proper way. Have one class that keeps track of the tasks and one class that does the tasks. Not this self-forking madness where you keep a reference to the main instance by a enum variable.

---

### Thread-safety

I was wondering about the thread-safety of your code, so I tested if threads start directly after the `start` method is called.

```
    for(int threads = 0; threads < 10; threads++){
        final int thred = threads;
        System.out.println("Creating thread "+thred);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Thread "+thred);
            }

        }).start();
        System.out.println("Created thread "+thred);
    }
```

The output?

```
Creating thread 0
Created thread 0
Creating thread 1
Created thread 1
Creating thread 2
Created thread 2
Thread 0
Thread 1
Creating thread 3
Thread 2
Created thread 3
Creating thread 4
Created thread 4
Thread 3
Creating thread 5
Thread 4
Created thread 5
Creating thread 6
Thread 5
Created thread 6
Creating thread 7
Created thread 7
Creating thread 8
Thread 6
Created thread 8
Thread 7
Creating thread 9
Thread 8
Created thread 9
Thread 9
```

Oh dear. It seems I can create three threads before any threads have even started running.

**It is not required for the JVM to start running your thread when you create it.**

Thus, you can exceed your max threads here:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    run = true;
    CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.getAndIncrement();
    while (run) {
        while (mailsToSend.peek() != null) {
            int currentThreads = CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.get();
            if (currentThreads < MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL && mailsToSend.size() > (MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD * currentThreads)) {
                new Thread(this).start();
            }
            MimeMessage message = mailsToSend.remove();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
    if (CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.decrementAndGet() < 1) {
        getErrorThread().start();
    }
    run = false;
}
```

There's a full queue already of 15000 mails (remember, threads are allowed to be suspended indefinitely, so I can add 15k mails before the VM starts your thread). First thread is created and run. It increments to 1. We put the limit at 2. It sees there's mail, and currently 1 thread. It adds a new thread and sends a message.

The message sending is done, but the other thread hasn't started yet. So we create a new thread.

Repeat until we have ~14975 threads.

That was a single thread breaking your code - so synchronization is not gonna help.

Though whatever you do, you'll want to have synchronization as well.

```
        while (mailsToSend.peek() != null) {
            int currentThreads = CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.get();
            if (currentThreads < MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL && mailsToSend.size() > (MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD * currentThreads)) {
                new Thread(this).start();
            }
            MimeMessage message = mailsToSend.remove();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
```

There's 100 mails. Thread cap at 3 threads.
Thread 1 grabs a mail, starts a thread, sends a mail.
Thread 2 grabs a mail, retrieves the thread counter, suspends.
Thread 1 returns from sending mail, grabs a mail, retrieves the thread counter, suspends.
Thread 2 creates a thread, sends a mail.
Thread 1 creates a thread, sends a mail.

You now have 4 threads.

---

So how do we fix this?

First, we need synchronization for starting a new thread.

At the top of the class:

```
private static final Object lockObject = new Object();
```

And in the run method:

```
        while (mailsToSend.peek() != null) {
            MimeMessage message = mailsToSend.remove();                
            synchronized(lockObject){
                int currentThreads = CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.get();
                if (currentThreads < MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL && mailsToSend.size() > (MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD * currentThreads)) {
                    new Thread(this).start();
                }
            }
            sendMessage(message);
        }
```

Hurray, synchronization!

Also, I just murdered your throughput (for every mail acquired, a thread must get a lock and free a lock). Clearly, this situation doesn't work.

... additionally, I just realized that you have this:

```
    while (run) {
        while (mailsToSend.peek() != null) {
            int currentThreads = CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.get();
            if (currentThreads < MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL && mailsToSend.size() > (MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD * currentThreads)) {
                new Thread(this).start();
            }
            MimeMessage message = mailsToSend.remove();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

That's a spinloop. If there's no mail left, check if there's more mail.

And you have 100 threads spinlooping.

Poor server.

---

So how are we gonna keep it thread-safe AND performant?

Well, first we need to get rid of the spin loop. If there's mail, the queue should start, and if mail is gone, the queue should stop.

For the start condition, you can modify `addMail` to check if there are threads running at all. This is a pain when dealing with 15000 mails, so consider having a scheduler that periodically checks if the mail queue is empty (every 5 seconds?).

For the stop condition, well, once the queue is empty, kill your threads. It's as simple as that.

You could even have a single "main" thread that doesn't die, then you could get rid of the scheduler. This "main" thread could sleep for 5 seconds if it didn't find any mail.

...

I took another look at your code. I'm still not fully understanding the enum hack. Are you... having multiple threads running the same runnable?

... what. (By the way, this gives you yet another bug, where a previously waiting-for-start thread will get started and set `run` to true).

Next, now that we're rid of the spin loop, we need to fix synchronization for starting new threads.

It's not possible to precisely limit the amount of created threads based on the size of the queue. For that, you'd need to determine the size of `mailsToSend`, but you can't do that without locking access to `mailsToSend`. That would require synchronization... which would give you all this locking madness for grabbing a single mail.

You're better off just doing as you do now, mostly - use `mailsToSend.size()` and just naively trust it. Besides, a few extra threads don't matter that much - either you have work to do and could use some extra threads, or you're not doing much and can handle having to clean up a mess.

What's more concerning is fixing the case where more threads than the cap are created. To fix this, you can use double checked locking:

```
private static Thread threadIncreaser;
private static final Object threadIncreaserLockObject = new Object();

...
//in addMail/addMails
if(threadIncreaser == null){
    synchronized(threadIncreaserLockObject){
        if(threadIncreaser == null){
            threadIncreaser = new Thread(new Runnable(){ ... });
            threadIncreaser.start();
        }
    }
}
```

With the runnable as such:

```
public void run(){
    int size = mailsToSend.size();
    int currentThreads = CURRENT_THREADS_SEND_MAIL.get();
    while (currentThreads < MAX_THREADS_SEND_MAIL && size > (MAX_ELEMENTS_BEFORE_NEW_THREAD * currentThreads)) {
        new Thread(MailQueue.INSTANCE).start();
        currentThreads++;
    }
}
```

This way, only 1 thread is responsible for running `mailsToSend.size()`. This should save a lot of checking `mailsToSend.size()`, which is basically iterating over all the mails.

And that's both the thread starting and spin looping fixed.

Comment: FYI, the use of enums to manage Singletons is now a "best practice". it is a pattern which though obscure, initially, is also very effective. It may not be implemented very visibly in this question, or even necessary, though.

Comment: @rolfl indeed it's for the singleton I did it. But Pimgd is correct with the thread safety. The original code before modification of multiple threads was intended for just 1 thread who sends the mails.

Answer (score 5):

It's very readable and you make extensive use of `LOGGER`.

> I also implemented some more threads for sending when the load becoming greater.

And here's exactly where I'd expect more logs. If I read your code correctly (I'm no Java expert), you don't check if your threads get started. Your total amount of threads running concurrent says something about the load, which seems import in your context. Make sure you can somehow log this load.

A `LOGGER.info` near the creation of the `Thread` in `addMail` would do just that.